# Paragraph being separated into 2 lines

Tags: html

So I'm having a sorta minor issue that is really bothering me. I'm trying to make a single line but the live site is separating the h3 and the sup onto two separate lines.

```
<p><h3><b><font color=" crimson";>CONSENT</font></b></h3> &nbsp;<sup>
Forgot? I got you &nbsp; &nbsp;</sup><a
href="http://www.exampledomain.com/example"
target="_black">Script</a></p>
```

The concept is to have the "Forgot? I got you" and the button be on the same line but spaced a little further from the word "Consent".

Comment: where is the HTML?

Comment: So many errors. You can't have a `<h3>` as a child of a `<p>`, the `<font>` doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: In addition to the invalid styles noted by @j08691, you'll want to ensure that you don't have any custom CSS that could be applying non-default styles to these elements, which could affect how they appear (and would be extremely important for us to see).

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't really provided an exact example of what you want your result to look like, you might consider using the following mark-up :

```
<h3 style='color: crimson; display:inline-block;'>
    CONSENT&nbsp;&nbsp;
</h3>
<small>
  Forgot? I got you 
  <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/example" target="_blank">Script</a>
</small>
```

**What this does :**

- `<h3>` and other heading tags are block level elements, which means that they will take not be rendered inline by default. You can change this by indicating that you want to display them inline by using `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;`
- The `<font>` tag hasn't been used in ages, you are better off simply applying a style attribute to the most relavent tag to style your contents.
- You were previously using all of these tags within a `<p>` tag, which can constitute invalid markup. They have each been broken out, if you need some type of container tag, you can use a `<div>`.
- Replaced the superscript tag `<sup>` with a small tag `<small>` to keep everything on the same line. You could replace this if you preferred.
- Previously, you were using `target="_black"`, which undoubtedly you meant to be `target="_blank"` for your `<a>` tag.
- Generally, you would want to avoid using an abundance of inline style tags in favor of using an actual CSS file along with `class` attributes.

**Example**

```html
<h3 style='color: crimson; display:inline-block;'>
    CONSENT&nbsp;&nbsp;
</h3>
<small>
      Forgot? I got you 
      <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/example" target="_black">Script</a>
</small>
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry, I'm just starting and was unable to find the answers as to how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a lot of work but really you could achieve this with simple CSS. As simple as it gets would be using a vertical-align on a `<span>` element, unfortunately `vertical-align: middle;` does NOT work directly on your `<p>` or `<h3>` tags. There are plenty of other ways to achieve this with separate `<div>`'s and all but here is the most basic.

HTML:

```
<span class="vAlign">
    <h3 class="crimson flt-left vAlign">CONSENT</h3>
    &nbsp;
    <p class="vAlign"><a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/example"
    target="_black">Forgot? I got you</p>
</span>
```

And CSS

```
.flt-left{
    float: left;
}
.crimson {
    color: crimson;
}
.vAlign {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm just beginning and trying to learn everything but this was really preventing me from continuing